# ViewPager inside listview scrolling issue

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

In my app I am using `ListView`, in the `ListView` each row is a `ViewPager`, in `Viewpager` adapter inflating a layout which consists 3 ImageViews and 2 TextViews, every thing is works fine, but
vertical scrolling is not so smooth.

Here is my question

1. Can I use `ViewPager` as a list item?
2. Some people saying that we shouldn't use the `ViewPager` as list item, then is there any alternative in my case?

Comment: The first question I'd asked is if you're using the ViewHolder pattern in your adapter.

Comment: Yes i am using the ViewHolder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

After some home work i figured out the solution  for my issue.

1.Can i use ViewPager inside ListView?

NO:

Cause:

it is not a good idea to use ViewPager inside ListView, The reason is in ViewPager onInstantiate() method we are inflating pager layout, during the vertical scrolling  of the Listview, for every new view in List adapter we have to inflate pager layout so it is expensive.

Solution:

I have used ViewFlipper(here the ViewFlipper is the customized one) with one static child, so vertical scrolling becomes so smooth because no extra layout inflating during list adapter scrolling, when user starts swiping horizontally on the flipper, 
then i added view to flipper dynamically and during the list adapter views recycling i removed dynamically added views from the list adapter.